# How to select widgets by class name like in CSS in Kivy?

Tags: python, css, kivy, classname

For example I want to put a background color to all the buttons in the application :

```
<Layout1>:
    <BoxLayout>:
        <Button>:
            text: "btn 1"
        <Button>:
            text: "btn 2"
        <Button>:
            text: "btn 3"
    <Button>:
        text: "Another button outside the boxlayout"

<Layout2>:
    <GridLayout>:
        cols: 2
        <Button>:
            text: "btn 1 in a grid"
        <Button>:
            text: "btn 2 in a grid"
```

But I don't want to do that by hand for all of them like this :

```
...
    <Button>:
        text: "btn 1"
        background_color: (1, 0, 0, 1)
    <Button>:
        text: "btn 2"
        background_color: (1, 0, 0, 1)
    <Button>:
        text: "btn 3"
        background_color: (1, 0, 0, 1)
...
```

So I'm looking for a shorter way like if we can put a class like in CSS to all of the buttons and access them by the class name. Something like that :

```
...
    <Button>:
        text: "btn 1"
        class: "btn_class"
    <Button>:
        text: "btn 2"
        class: "btn_class"
    <Button>:
        text: "btn 3"
        class: "btn_class"
...
```

And in python code :

```
for btn in get_widgets_by_classname("btn_class") :
    btn.background_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
```

In the documentation https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#overview it says :

> You can target a specific class of widgets (similar to the CSS concept
> of a class) by using the cls attribute (e.g. cls=MyTestWidget)

but it's not that clear for me about the use of the cls attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Good day. In kvlang, you have two options for creating template widgets.

1. Create a Custom Widget:

Custom Widgets allows you to create a new, defined widget.

```
<CustomButton@Button>:
    background_color: (1,0,0,1)
```

Then use the button wherever you want with the following syntax.
`CustomButton:`

2. Use rules:

At the start of the script, assign properties to a widget using the following syntax.

```
<Button>:
    background_color:(1,0,0,1)
```

Any widget called after its creation will be created with those attributes.